# How can I tell whether a pointer points to the stack or to the heap?

Tags: delphi, pointers

If I have a pointer to memory, how can I tell if it points to a heap based structure (and should thus be freed) or whether it points to the stack (as thus should not be touched)?

Here's some sample code.

```
TMiniStack<T> = record
private
  SP: integer;
  fData: array[0..DefaultStackSize - 1] of T;
public
  procedure Free;
  procedure Push(const Item: T); inline;
  function Pop: T; inline;
end;

StaticFactory<T> = class
public type
  PStack = ^Stack;
  Stack = TMiniStack<T>;
public
  class function Create(Size: integer = DefaultStackSize); static;
end;

implementation
```

What do I put in the assert in the `Free` 'destructor' to enable to log attempts to free a Stack based stack?

```
procedure TMiniStack<T>.Free;
begin
  AssertOrLog(@Self is really on the heap,'This stack does not live on the heap');
  Finalize(Items, Count);
  FreeMemory(@Self);
end;
```

I seem to remember there being a `IsValidPointer` method. But cannot find any documentation for it.
I would like to be able to differentiate between stack/heap mistakes and other pointer issues.

**EDIT: Choosen solution**
To aid in debugging I've added a `IsHeapBased: TGUID` field. That is only included if debug is defined. An assert in the free method checks for this and gives feedback. I've also added a capacity field (debug only) to detect Stack overflow.
The purpose of this checking is solely to aid in debugging.

```
{$IFDEF DEBUG}
MagicHeapFlag: TGUID = '{EF227045-27A9-4EF3-99E3-9D279D58F9A0}';
{$ENDIF}

class function MiniStack<T>.Create(Size: integer = DefaultSize): PStack;
begin
  Result:= AllocMem(SizeOf(TMiniStack<T>) - (DefaultSize * SizeOf(T)) + (Size * SizeOf(T)));
  Result.SP:= 0;
{$IFDEF DEBUG}
  Result.IsHeapBased:= MagicHeapFlag;
  Result.HeapSize:= Size;
{$ENDIF}
end;

{$IFDEF DEBUG}
function TMiniStack<T>.capacity: Integer;
begin
  if IsHeapBased = MagicHeapFlag then begin
    Result:= HeapSize;
  end
  else Result:= DefaultSize;
end;
{$ENDIF}

procedure TMiniStack<T>.Free;
begin
{$IFDEF DEBUG}
  Assert(IsHeapBased = MagicHeapFlag, 'Do not call free on stack based MiniStacks');
{$ENDIF}
  Finalize(Items, count);
  FreeMem(@Self);
end;
```

Comment: If you know your maximum stack size you can use something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2741560/327083  to see where you are, then determine if the address is within the range of the current stack.  Agreed with @DavidHeffernan mind you, that this seems an exercise of dubious utility...

Comment: @J... not all stacks have the same size of course

Comment: FreeMemory is not the right way to dispose of a dynamically allocated record. The routine "Dispose" should be use instead.

Comment: You can get away with "FreeMemory" in this situation as long as "T" isn't a managed type, but if "T" is string, dynamic array, Interface,etc you will get memory leaks.
And it sounds to me there is something fundamentally wrong with your architecture if you don't know if a record pointer needs to be freed or not.

Comment: @KenBourassa, BTW well spotted on the Dispose part. I decided to finalize the references explicitly, because only references that have not been popped yet need to be finalized and I don't want to incur overhead for checking the references that have been popped already.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the architecture, but because it is a library function I want to add all the debug code I can. This helps in getting debug info as early as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't realistically hope to distinguish between stack and heap memory in this way. You say "the stack", but there are many. One per thread. You'd need to check the reserved addresses of all the stacks. And how will you find a list of all the stacks to do that checking without encountering a terrible race condition?

It is folly to try to get a record to behave differently depending on whether it is allocated automatically on the stack, or dynamically on the heap. Those behaviour variations need to be handled by the consumer of the record.

A scenario to make you re-consider is that where your record is contained inside another type (record or class). The instance of the containing type may be heap allocated but you must not free the contained record, even though it resides on the heap.

The bottom line of heap allocation is that you need to remember when you allocated off the heap and ensure that you free anything allocated on the heap. If you forget who owns the memory by a pointer you are doing it wrong.

Don't continue down the dead end trail that you have started along.

Comment: It's not that, it's just that I want to be able to track down errors. I'll add some debug code/data with `ifdefs` that checks the history of the records and informs me of the status.

Comment: You don't need to do that. Your memory manager will do that for you any time you free an address that wasn't dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 3):

You could probably contrive some mechanism to determine the current stack "depth" and using that in combination with the stack pointer determine whether or not a given address lies in the range currently occupied by the stack.

But this is likely to be a lot of work both in terms of implementation and runtime execution.

If I interpret your aim correctly, you wish to prevent situations where someone has statically allocated a **TMiniStack** on the stack and then called the **Free** method inappropriately.

I would suggest that if this is a likely situation that needs to be avoided, then the simplest means for achieving this is to eliminate the possibility that it might occur.

For me I would choose either static allocation or dynamic, but not allow both.  Using a record type it is impossible to prevent dynamic allocation and so by choosing a record you have to accept this.  In which case providing the "Free" method on the record type is simply wrong and dangerously misleading to consumers of the record type.

The alternative is to prevent static allocation, using a class rather than a record.  But this then would require that consumers of the **TMiniStack** always be responsible for allocating and correctly de-allocating the mini-stacks.

However, this can be avoided by not exposing your **TMiniStack** class and instead using an interface, implementing the **TMiniStack** class privately as a reference counted object, exposing only the interface and factory types:

```
  interface

  type
    IMiniStack<T> = interface
      procedure Push(aValue: T);
      function Pop: T;
    end;

    MiniStack<T> = class
      class function Create(aSize: Integer): IMiniStack<T>; reintroduce;
    end;


  implementation

  type
    TMiniStack<T> = class(TInterfacedObject, IMiniStack<T>)
    private
      fItems: array of T;
    protected
      constructor Create(aSize: Integer);
      procedure Push(aValue: T);
      function Pop: T;
    end;


  constructor TMiniStack<T>.Create(aSize: Integer);
  begin
    inherited Create;
    SetLength(fItems, aSize);
  end;

  function TMiniStack<T>.Pop: T;
  begin
    // left as exercise for the reader
  end;

  procedure TMiniStack<T>.Push(aValue: T);
  begin
    // left as exercise for the reader
  end;


  class function MiniStack<T>.Create(aSize: Integer): IMiniStack<T>;
  begin
    result := TMiniStack<T>.Create(aSize);
  end;
```

In use, this would look something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ms: IMiniStack<Integer>;
begin
  ms := MiniStack<Integer>.Create(100);
end;
```

Since you are already using a factory, the impact on your consumers will I think be negligible, and they need not concern themselves with if or when they should free the mini-stacks that they allocate - the reference counting will take care of that for them.

Comment: This is sound advice. However, I'd guess that Johan specifically wants to allow stack allocation for perf reasons, based on his previous questions.

Comment: Wanting it isn't the same as needing it.  ;)  I haven't seen his other questions that you are referring to, and this particular question makes no mention of any performance concerns that the stated, desired approach specifically addresses (a bad case of premature optimization perhaps ?)  :)

Comment: The reason de'etre for the MiniStack is performance. If it does not significantly outperform TStack<T> then it serves no purpose. I use the ministack in a tree to prevent a recursive solution. Putting the ministack in place halved the runtime vs a stack implementation using a normal TStack. It also made it slightly faster than a recursive solution. The reference counting will kill performance here because of the hidden try-finally. If I keep the stack around instead of recreating it at each function call I run into multi-threading issues. I think I'll just make the stack to be Stack only.

Comment: @Deltics Possibly not premature. Heap allocation is astoundingly slow. Especially in a cpu bound threaded program. Stack allocation is free. I avoid heap allocs in perf critical bottlenecks like the plague.

Comment: Fair enough then.  In which case yes, go with recommendation "a" in my answer:  remove the "Free" method and the factory class and any other inference that heap allocation is permissible.  I would then say that inappropriate heap use should be left simply  use as an out-of-bounds error.  This may be difficult to detect at runtime but should be easily identified during code review.  Also  I wonder how much of your performance gain comes from putting your type on the stack and how much from simply eliminating all the unused baggage that TStack<T> involves ?  Worth checking maybe?

Comment: Having checked the TStack<> implementation there is a LOT of overhead in there that I suspect is responsible for a large part of the gains you saw when you stopped using it.  Use of the stack might also contribute, but it's not the only source of savings.  Also, afaik (and certainly ime) **try..finally** is not a significant overhead except in the case where exceptions are involved.  Refcounting does add some overhead, but only when the refs are counted, so if you ensure to pass your stacks around using **const** references there will be precisely 1 AddRef() and 1 Release().